# How to compile a C, C++, Python code on AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to compile and run a c, c++, python, java code on aws lambda function. I am working on a project that user can upload their code and It will compile and run the code and return the output of the program to the user through aws lambda function. For compiling the codes I have to install the compilers in aws lambda function but I don't know how to do that. Is that possible to install in lambda function?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to install additional operating system dependencies like the `gcc` compiler.  Additionally, even if you could I don't think you'd *want* to do that as it would dramatically increase the startup time of the Lambda.  Remember that you may have thousands of Lamda's running and they may be re-initiated at any time.

A better way might be to have a Docker container that has all of the compilers available to your customers and deploy that to [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/).  That way you could keep the isolation of Lambda but customize the runtime environment more.